# Map SDK for highlighted countries and there divisions

Tags: android, ios, mapkit, mapbox

One requirement of my app is to select and highlight some countries and there administrative divisions from a world-map.

e.g like this : [theartofasking](http://theartofasking.com/)

This should be able in offline-mode and for cross-plattform development (iOS / Android)

How can i do that ?

Comment: using google maps i had divided a nation into different levels using KML layers. But this was done using jquery. See if u can use this concept of kml layers in java.

Answer (score 0):

See http://justinmiller.io/posts/2015/01/20/anatomy-of-a-travel-map/ for some background on how I was able to use Mapbox GL to do this in JavaScript. Using the native-side library, once https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/352 is unblocked, the same could be accomplished on mobile.

Comment: thank you for your reply but i need to bind and render geojson data. it seems to be not possibile with mapbox  ... right ?